# Not seeing Devise folder in Rails App after install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I ran the following and have the devise gem included but I don't see the devise folder anywhere so I can override the views.

- $rails generate devise:install
- $rails generate devise User

I do not see this folder: app/views/devise/

I'm trying to follow this tutorial (http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-bootstrap-devise-cancan.html) but am getting hung up on a step where it deals with devise.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rails g devise:views` will help you